# How can I write a single cucumber step definition where multiple parameters are optional?

Tags: cucumber

With reference to a previous question/answer 
[In a method that take multiple optional parameters, how can any but the first be specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695431/in-a-method-that-take-multiple-optional-parameters-how-can-any-but-the-first-be)

```
def foo(fruit=nil,cut=nil,topping=nil)
  fruit    ||= 'apple'
  cut      ||= 'sliced'
  topping  ||= 'ice cream'
  # some logic here
end

foo(nil,nil,'hot fudge')
```

How can I wrap this example into a single cucumber step definition where multiple parameters are also optional i.e. So I can pass any number of parameters into the step?

Like these,

```
I enter cut 'sliced' and topping 'Ice cream'. 
I enter fruit 'apple and topping 'Ice cream'.
I enter cut 'sliced'
```

I want to replicate the user only supplying certain values as the page already has default values in the fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need regex. If you write the step so it's natural, then you can run it and cucumber will tell you what you need.

```
➜  Fruit git:(master) ✗ cucumber
Feature: Toppings

  Scenario: Add fruit # features/test.feature:3
    When I enter cut "sliced" and topping "Ice cream" # features/test.feature:4

1 scenario (1 undefined)
1 step (1 undefined)
0m0.001s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When(/^I enter cut "(.*?)" and topping "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

And use double-quotes. That helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default values like in the method above:

```
Then (/^I enter (cut|fruit) '(.*?)'( and topping '(.*?)')?$/) do |action, param1, topping, param2|
  if param1.strip.empty?
    param1 = (action == 'cut' ? 'sliced' : 'apple')
  end
  print "I #{action} #{param1}"
  if topping
    param2 = 'ice cream' if param2.strip.empty?
    print " and topping #{param2}"
  end
  print "\n"
  # some logic here
end
```

else:

```
Then (/^I enter (cut|fruit) '(.*?)'( and topping '(.*?)')?$/) do |action, param1, topping, param2|
  print "I #{action} #{param1}"
  if topping
    print " and topping #{param2}"
  end
  print "\n"
  # some logic here
end
```